# Pass data from controller to View - MVC

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I´m tryin to make a query to receive all data in my database to show it in my view.

but it´s not working. i can´t figured it out what is going on because i don´t get any error.

anybody can help with this pls?

thanks in advance

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult Details(int id = 0)
            {
                Persons p= db.persons.Find(id);

                var query = from a in db.images
                            where a.Id_Person== id
                            select a.FileName;
                ViewBag.ImgRev= query;

                if (mag == null)
                {
                    return HttpNotFound();
                }

                return View(p);
            }
```

**View:**

```
@foreach (var p in ViewBag.ImgRev)
        { 
          <div>
            <img src="~/Files/" + @p /></div>
        }
```

Comment: have you debugged and seen that there is data?

Comment: have check it.. its null.. what do i wrong? i miss something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linq statement will not have evaluated before it is assigned to the `ViewBag`.

Try:

**Controller:**

```
ViewBag.ImgRev = query.ToList();
```

**View:**

```
@ {
    var imgList = ViewBag.ImgRev as IEnumerable<string>;
}

@foreach (var p in imgList)
{ 
    <div><img src="~/Files/" + @p /></div>
}
```

Alternative using ViewModel:

```
public class SomePageViewModel
{
    public Persons Persons { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> Files { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
...
var model = new SomePageViewModel { Persons = p, Files = query.ToList() };
return model;
```

**View:**

```
@foreach (var file in Model.Files)
{ 
    <div><img src="~/Files/" + @file /></div>
}
```

Comment: romoku where come your <Image>  from?

Comment: I guessed the class name.

Comment: i try your code but i get now this error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.   :Breakpoint foreach

Comment: i have set a breakpont in the controller and have check the query and still are null....

Comment: Make sure it's connected to the database.

Comment: @user2232273 - I would suggest to use the alternative method (ViewModel).